# How do I prevent duplicate entries in a database when inserting new entries with SQL?

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

I am writing a program where I need to insert data into a database using SQL. However I have realised I need to use validation to ensure the same x.name isn't entered twice into the database. (FormBoxes is a list of objects) The code needs to read from the database and not add data which is already in the ID column

Answer (score 0):

I tend to believe that you want to avoid duplicates in this column at all times, not only for this specific piece of code. If so, I would advise to simply create a unique constraint on that column:

```
ALTER TABLE tblDate ADD CONSTRAINT ID_UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT UNIQUE (ID);
```

Then your RDBMS will enforce data integrity (that's something they do very well). If you try to insert a duplicate, you will get a specific error, that you can catch and handle in your application (in your use case, probably ignore it).

Comment: Sorry if I'm being a little doltish, but how would i implement this?

Comment: @Bill435: actually you just have to execute the sql order in my answer against your database.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one, but be suggested you change your table with ID to be indexed:

```
insert into tblDate  (ID)
SELECT drvd1.tID FROM   (
select @ID as tID) as drvd1 left join tblDate  on ID=drvd1.tID
where tblDate.ID is NULL;
```

Above can't be used if your database is not SQL Server, for MS Access I Have create another

Answer (score 0):

For ms Access you can do with this with note, at least you have 1 record in your tblDate:

```
insert into tblDate (ID)
SELECT myAlias.tID
FROM (SELECT top 1 @ID AS tID
             FROM tblDate
      union all
      SELECT tblDate.ID
             FROM tblDate
             WHERE (((tblDate.ID)=@ID)))  AS myAlias
GROUP BY myAlias.tID
HAVING (((Count(myAlias.tID))=1));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are forgetting that Access pays no attention to named parameters. It is the order of that the parameters are added to the parameters collection that matters. They are just "?" to Access so we need 2 parameters both assigned the same value.

The `Using...End Using` blocks will close and dispose your database objects.

Don't use `.AddWithValue`. See http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/
and
https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/
and another one:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/195937/addwithvalue-performance-and-plan-cache-implications
Here is another
https://andrevdm.blogspot.com/2010/12/parameterised-queriesdont-use.html

Only create one command outside the For loop and populate the parameters collection only one. Inside the loop just change the values of the parameters.

```
Private Sub UpdateAccess()
    Using cn As New OleDbConnection("Your connection string"),
            cmd As New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO tblDate (ID) VALUES (@ID) WHERE Not EXISTS(Select * FROM tblDate WHERE ID = @ID2)", cn)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", OleDbType.Integer)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID2", OleDbType.Integer)
        cn.Open()
        For Each X In FormBoxes
            cmd.Parameters("@ID").Value = X.Name
            cmd.Parameters("@ID2").Value = X.Name
        Next
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: This did not work, but maybe i did not implement it correctly @Mary

Comment: @Bill435 Did you get an error? "did not work" is not very informative. Exactly what didn't work?

Comment: aha sorry, the error message I received was `'Missing ), ], or Item in query expression 'Not EXISTS(Select * FROM tblDate WHERE ID = @ID2`

Comment: @Bill435 Do you have a close parenthesis `) `after the @ID2 before the closing quote `"`? ...`= @ID2)"`

Comment: Yes, I do have a close parenthesis

Comment: I was missing parenthesis elsewhere but now i have `System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Query input must contain at least one table or query.'`

Comment: Is tblData the real name of your table in the database?